# Jsonify data not returning to ajax call

Tags: python, ajax, flask, leaflet, geojson

I have an app where I am using flask, python, ajax, json, javascript, and leaflet.  This app reads a csv file, puts it into json format, then returns it to an ajax call.  My issue is that the geojson is not being returned.  In the console, I am getting a 5000 NetworkError in the console log.  The end result is to use the return geojson in a leaflet map layer.  If I remove the jsonify, the return works fine, but it is a string of course, and this wont work for the layer.

As you can see, I have a simple alert("success") in the ajax success part.  This is not being executed.  Nor is the alert(data).
I do have jsonify in the from Flask import statement.
Thank you for the help

Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : '/process',
  data: {
     chks: chks
     }
 })
 .success(function(data){
   alert("success"); // I am doing this just to get see if I get back here.  I do not
   alert(data);
```

python/flask

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
   data = request.form['chks']
   rawData = csv.reader(open('static/csvfile.csv', 'r'), dialect='excel')
   count = sum(1 for row in open('static/csvfile.csv))
   template =\
      ''' \
      {"type" : "Feature",
         "geometry"  : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [%s, %s]},
         "properties" : {"name" : "%s" }
         }%s
      '''

   output = \
      ''' \
      {"type" : "Feature Collection",
           "features" : [
      '''
    iter = 0
    separator = ","
    lastrow = ""
    for row in rawData:
      iter += 1 // this is used to skip the first line of the csv file
      if iter >=2:
         id = row[0]
         lat = row[1]
         long = row[2]
         if iter != count:
            output += template % (row[2], row[1], row[0], separator)
         else:
            output += template % (row[2], row[1], row[0], lastrow)


   output += \
      ''' \
       ]}
      '''

   return jsonify(output)
```

More Info - taking David Knipe's info into hand, If I remove the jsonify from my return statement, it returns what I expect, and I can output the return in an alert.  It looks like this

```
{ "type" : "Feature Collection",
"features" : [
    {"type" : "Feature",
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ -86.28, 32.36]},
    "properties" : {"name" : "Montgomery"}
    },
    { "type" : "Feature",
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ -105.42, 40.30]},
    "properties" : {"name" : "Boulder"}
            },
]}
```

If I take that data and hard code it into the ajax success, then pass it to the leaflet layer code like this - it will work, and my points will be displayed on my map

```
...
.success(function(data){
   var pointsHC= { "type" : "Feature Collection",
"features" : [
    {"type" : "Feature",
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ -86.28, 32.36]},
    "properties" : {"name" : "Montgomery"}
    },
    { "type" : "Feature",
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ -105.42, 40.30]},
    "properties" : {"name" : "Boulder"}
            },
]};

// leaflet part
var layer = L.geoJson(pointsHC, {
   pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){
   return L.circleMarker( ...
```

If I do not hard code and pass the data via a variable, it does not work, and I get and invalid geoJson object.  I have tried it with both the final semi-colon removed and not removed, and no love either way

```
    ...
.success(function(data){
    // leaflet part
var layer = L.geoJson(data, {
   pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){
   return L.circleMarker( ...
```

Comment: is `request.form['chks']` properly populated

Comment: @Busturdust - Yes.  if I change the code to return chks, I get what I expect.  Also, if I remove the jsonify and just return (output), I get what I expect, but as a string.

Comment: There are a few typos in the above code that I fixed.  I hope I go them all.  Due to security issues, I could not copy past my code.  That is why the typos are there.

Answer (score 0):

So it works if you don't try to parse the JSON, but if you do then it fails. Your JSON is invalid:

- As loganbertram pointed out, you're missing a `"` on `"Feature Collection"`.
- You're missing a `"` on `"properties"`.
- `output = template % ...` should be `output += template % ...` - you're appending to `output`, not replacing it.
- the `features` array will have a trailing comma (unless it is empty).

Although actually in your code `features` will always be empty anyway: you set `iter = 0`, never change its value, and then don't do the `output = ...` bit because `iter < 2`.

Are you sure you actually want to use `jsonify`? As I understand it, that turns any object into a JSON string. But `output` is already a JSON string - or should be, if you fix the various bugs loganbertram and I have spotted. In that case the client-side code will not fail trying to parse JSON. But if you `jsonify` something that's already JSON, you'll get something like this:

```
"{\"type\" : \"Feature\",
   \"geometry\"  : {
...
```

which the javascript will then convert back to the original JSON string, instead of a JSON object.

Actually, it would be better to rewrite the whole thing so it constructs an object instead of a string, and then calls `jsonify` on that object. But I don't know enough Python to give more details easily.

Comment: Oh, and you need an extra `}` at the end. And get rid of the `;`, that's not valid JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Sorry, but there were several typos in my Stack post that I have fixed.  I looked into what you have said about a JSON string.  If I don't jsonify it, alert the output, then copy past (hardcode)  the output into the javascript, it works.  If I take the passed data (no hardcode), I get an invalid Geojson object.  I am using the data as a point layer in leaflet.  Why would one work and the other not, when I believe it is the same data.  The delivery is all that is different.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You still have the trailing comma at the end of the `features` array. That's not valid JSON. But it works when you hard-code it into the javascript code because it's not JSON, it's javascript. (Javascript allows trailing commas.) The way I'd do this (if I'd been ordered not to redo it using the sensible approach I recommended in my final paragraph) would be instead of having a trailing `,` in the template, have a leading `%s` in the template which is replaced by `''` on the first iteration and `','` afterwards. E.g. `separator = ''`, then in the loop (after `output += ...`) `separator = ','`.

Comment: I changed up the code so that that trailing comma is removed on the last point.  Still no love.  I am still confused as to why it would matter where the data came from.  The hard coded data is a copy paste of the data that came thru the function and was outputted thru the alert.  The only difference is that I added a ; at the end of the hardcoded variable.  The hard coded variable works in leaflet.  It is only when I pass the data thru the function leaflet calls it invalid geojson.  Only it is still javascript, it is still a geojson string.

Comment: I reckon `count` is out by 1. It's the number of lines in the file, including the heading. The last line is at `iter == count-1`, so it's still adding the comma. The way I suggested was less error-prone: write the first feature with no comma, and subsequent lines with a comma at the start (not the end). Then you don't have to read the file twice to count lines.

Comment: If you want to read the raw JSON string client-side before JSON parsing, add `dataType: 'text'` to the argument to `$.ajax`. Then `data` will be the unparsed JSON. You can test validity of JSON at https://jsonlint.com/?json=null . (But that doesn't test it's valid for leaflet. I have no idea what leaflet even is.)